# Named Entity Recognition Cosine Similarity

Tags: python, nlp, word2vec, named-entity-recognition

I'm trying to use google's word2vec model (https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/ - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7XkCwpI5KDYNlNUTTlSS21pQmM/edit?usp=sharing) based on google news in Python 3.6.
I load the model using gensim package and specially `KeyedVectors` class (https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html). After, I use `similarity()` method, but I have some problems with named entities.

For example, I would compare and measure "Roger Federer" with "Michael Jordan" (and not "federer" with "jordan", because I wouldn't want to tokenize the single named entity), and with many named entities I got an error `word 'named_entities' is not in vocabulary`.

Is there any other pre-trained word2vec model which can be used to measure distance between named entities.

Comment: It would be much easier to help with at least part of your code. For now, it seems that you passed variable name `named_entities` rather than variable value, but I'm not sure without code.